# The zero polynomial in a commutative ring with unity

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynonial $p(x)= 4x^2+8x-16 \in \mathbb{Z_4[x]}.$ My understanding is that this is equal to the zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Z_4[x]}$.

I seem to be confused about determining whether $q(x)=x^2+x \in \mathbb{Z_2}[x]$ is also the zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$. Can someone help me clarify that?

Comment: The title and the first paragraph of your question suggest that you might think $\mathbb Z_4$ is a field. It isn't.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the title, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that $p(x)$ is equal to the zero polynomial in $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ is that $4,8,$ and $-16$ are all equal to $0$ *modulo* $4.$ That is, they are all integer multiples of $4,$ so have a remainder of $0$ when divided by $4.$ However, $q(x)$ is not equal to the zero polynomial in $\Bbb Z_2[x],$ since $1$ is not an even number.

More generally, if we are given a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\in\Bbb Z_m[x],$ where each $a_k$ is an integer, then for each $k,$ there is a unique integer $0\leq b_k<m$ such that $a_k-b_k$ is an integer multiple of $m.$ $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k$ is then equal to $f(x)$ in the ring $\Bbb Z_m[x],$ and $f(x)$ is equal to the zero polynomial if and only if each $b_k=0.$

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!

Comment: In particular $q = x^2+x \in {\Bbb Z}_2[x]$ is not the zero polynomial, but the function $z\mapsto q(z)$ from ${\Bbb Z}_2$ to ${\Bbb Z}_2$ is the zero function.

Comment: @coder22, you're welcome! Also, see Jamie Radcliffe's comment, for a very important clarification.